# getting in touch with ADCS/GNC engineers

Tags: discussion

I would like to publish an abstract/paper pretty soon about ADCS engineering. As I am learning about ADCS-engineering on my own I'd like to discuss the different results of my researches with people who are familiar with that topic.
 So I would like to know where I could get in touch with people who are active in that domain?

Would posting a link to my abstract on SE be OK, in order to get as much critics/feedback/.. as possible? If not where would be a proper place to discuss such precise topic?

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't do open-ended discussions, which seems to be what you are suggesting. You could however bring it up in [chat], once you have earned the small amount of reputation needed. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I think I ve asked it at least a dozend times in the chat. (with my previous account)

Comment: I'm happy to help you with this, get in touch with me in the Pod Bay chat room at SE Space Exploration or follow my profile and send me an email. If your paper is already prepared then the best test is to just submit it -- I recommend an AIAA journal.

Comment: @BrianLynch, thank you so much! I ll try to send you my abstract in 2 weeks or so (still have exams ftm). Do you have any experience with submitting papers on AIAA? I've never done that before...